# 501 error ScraPy - HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Got the error above. Ran through SO and only on 403 or 404 errors discussed.

Here are some stuff I tried to make it work.

- edited the user_agent to my string
- checked Reddit's robots.txt but no disallow on my crawl parameters
- tried to tweak URL and domains (didnt work)
- did scrapy shell ..same error but no explanation
- website works on my browser on laptop
- checked http 501, refers to "not implemented" or server does not support functionality

And the error fields

```
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reddit.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://www.reddit.com/robots.txt>
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reddit.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-04-07 17:34:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//> from <GET http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//>
2019-04-07 17:34:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (501) <GET https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//> (referer: None)
2019-04-07 17:34:01 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response **<501 https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed**
2019-04-07 17:34:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Codes

```
class RedditbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "redditgetter"
    allowed_domains = ['reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    custom_settings = {
       'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/redditdata.csv'
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        titles = response.css('.title.may-blank::text').extract()
        votes = response.css('.score.unvoted::text').extract()
        times = response.css('time::attr(title)').extract()

        for item in zip(titles,votes,times):

            scraped_info = {
                'title' : item[0],
                'vote' : item[1],
                'created_at' : item[2],
            }

            yield scraped_info
```

**UPDATE : the new error after indent and "//" corrected.**

```
2019-04-07 23:00:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-07 23:00:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-07 23:00:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-07 23:00:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reddit.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://www.reddit.com/robots.txt>
2019-04-07 23:00:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reddit.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-04-07 23:00:45 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/> from <GET http://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/>
2019-04-07 23:00:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/> (referer: None)
2019-04-07 23:00:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-04-07 23:00:47 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1287,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 101351,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 7, 15, 0, 47, 452284),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'memusage/max': 50294784,
 'memusage/startup': 50290688,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 7, 15, 0, 44, 502445)}
2019-04-07 23:00:47 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with your code implementation, it's just a typo in the URL. I was able to reproduce the issue (`501` status code) by sending a GET request to `https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones//` via https://reqbin.com/u4xxuehu

You simply need to remove the extra slash at the end of the URL to receive a `200 (OK)` status: https://reqbin.com/43le52w4

---

Edit regarding reddit scraping: your code doesn't have an error, it's successfully getting a response of 101351 bytes (you can check this yourself by printing the `response.body` in the `parse()` method): `'downloader/response_bytes': 101351`.

The problem is in the way that you're parsing the response. You're using CSS selectors (eg. `response.css('.title.may-blank::text')`) that aren't returning anything because there are no elements with such classes in the HTML (check the source of the web-page in the browser and look for the elements that you're trying to select). In fact, you'll notice that Reddit takes anti-crawling measures by assigning obscure classes to HTML elements.

However, upon inspecting the source code, it turns out that the end of the page contains JSON data wrapped in `<script id="data"></script>`, which includes information about posts (title, upvotes, etc). The information that you want to extract is structured as follows:

```
posts
└── models
    └── postId
        ├── title
        ├── score
        └── created
```

You can simply load and parse the JSON data to get the desired fields. Here's a working implementation of the `parse()` method:

```
def parse(self, response):

    # get the contents inside <script id="data"></script>
    data = response.css('#data::text').get()
    # remove anything before { and after } to get valid JSON
    data = re.findall(r"{.*}",str(data), re.MULTILINE)[0];
    jsonresponse = json.loads(data)

    titles = []
    votes = []
    times = []
    for post in jsonresponse["posts"]["models"]:
        titles.append(jsonresponse["posts"]["models"][post]["title"])
        votes.append(jsonresponse["posts"]["models"][post]["score"])
        times.append(jsonresponse["posts"]["models"][post]["created"])

    for item in zip(titles,votes,times):
        scraped_info = {
                'title' : item[0],
                'vote' : item[1],
                'created_at' : item[2],
        }
        yield scraped_info
```

Sample output:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/>
{'title': '[NO SPOILERS] GoT this viewing party invite today. What do you think?', 'vote': 133, 'created_at': 1554610745000}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55557800

Comment: That is strange, I did remove the double slash too but it threw me a error that something in Scrapy. Ok will test and respond shortly, thanks!

Comment: Thanks its correct. The error is from indentation which Im still trying to sort out. I picked up Python from JS, so not aware how picky Python is with the indents.

Comment: I solved the indent, its a foreign problem. That said, It sees 200 http now, but not crawling and no error messages thrown up so no clue wheres the issue. I attached the edited code and threads above.

Comment: @Thinkerer I updated my answer with a working parsing implementation. You can also see the output in the CSV file in the demo (in the files on the left).

Comment: Thanks for the link, really appreciate the effort to make it simple. The link works. One question, which part in inspect code do you spot the json? I tried search but unable to find. I added .json to url and tried to dump in analyzer, but did not see as clearly the hierachy.

Comment: Use Ctrl+U to see the full source code and search for "data" (including double quotes). Note that it's a huge blob of JSON.